# Twisted - should this code be run in separate threads

Tags: python, twisted

I am running some code that has X workers, each worker pulling tasks from a queue every second. For this I use twisted's `task.LoopingCall()` function. Each worker fulfills its request (scrape some data) and then pushes the response back to another queue. All this is done in the reactor thread since I am not deferring this to any other thread.

I am wondering whether I should run all these jobs in separate threads or leave them as they are. And if so, is there a problem if I call `task.LoopingCall` every second from each thread ?

Answer (score 2):

No, you shouldn't use threads.  You *can't* call `LoopingCall` from a thread (unless you use `reactor.callFromThread`), but it wouldn't help you make your code faster.

If you notice a performance problem, you may want to profile your workload, figure out where the CPU-intensive work is, and then put that work into multiple *processes*, spawned with `spawnProcess`.  You really can't skip the step where you figure out where the expensive work is, though: there's no magic pixie dust you can sprinkle on your Twisted application that will make it faster.  If you choose a part of your code which isn't very intensive and doesn't require blocking resources like CPU or disk, then you will discover that the overhead of moving work to a different process may outweigh any benefit of having it there.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use threads for that. Doing it all in the reactor thread is ok. If your scraping uses `twisted.web.client` to do the network access, it shouldn't block, so you will go as fast as it gets.

Comment: Yes, I am using twisted.web.client for scraping, I was worried though about the parsing part if it could somehow block the reactor thread.

Comment: parsing is fast. If you see that being a problem, you could use incremental parsing like in http://codespeak.net/lxml/parsing.html#the-feed-parser-interface

Answer (score 0):

First, beware that Twisted's reactor sometimes multithreads and assigns tasks without telling you anything. Of course, I haven't seen your program in particular.

Second, in Python (that is, in CPython) spawning threads to do non-blocking computation has little benefit. Read up on the [GIL (Global Interpreter Lock)](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).

Comment: "First, beware that Twisted's reactor sometimes multithreads" - not in any way that you can observe.  If you *ever* discover that your code is running in a non-reactor thread and you didn't ask for that, it's a bug, please report it (I know of no cases where this has ever happened).

Comment: Of course I didin't mean it multithreads randomly, Jean-Paul, please. I meant high-level abstractions may implement a multi-threaded reactor, and you might be unaware as user of the code. The lack of detail in the original post led me to believe OP might not be. That said, congratulations on the excellent work you guys do with Twisted.